# How to get the structure of a super frame header comming from qualcomm chip set diag

Tags: byte, communication, diagnostics, data-link-layer, qualcomm

I know that some Snapdragon QUALCOMM chipsets can send communication logs to upper level access. I also know the High-Level Data Link Control (HDLC) frame structure which each frame ends with 0x7e.

But this chip set sends some super frames that have a special structure and can violate this convention. As we know, the schema will be as follows:

[image: schema of the super frame and frames]

And byte stuffing is not used in super frame header, just in frames.

So, what is the structure of the super frame header or the convention which is used in that? In more precise terms, what is the representative of the bytes in the super frame header?

Is there a link? Or can some body tell me about it?